# Find Day of the Next Week , of the date entered

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
function getNextWeekDate(inputDate) {
    const [datePart, timePart] = inputDate.split(' ');
    const [day, month, year] = datePart.split('-');

    const dayInt = parseInt(day);
    const monthInt = parseInt(month) - 1;
    const yearInt = parseInt(year);

    // Create a Date object
    const date = new Date(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);

    const dayOfWeek = date.getDay();
    const daysToAdd = 7 - dayOfWeek;

    date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToAdd);

    const newDay = (date.getDate()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const newMonth = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const newYear = date.getFullYear();
    const newDate = `${newDay}-${newMonth}-${newYear}`;

    return newDate;
}
```

This is the function that i created in JS if i pass var n = getNextWeekDate("01-11-2023"); date like this then function should return 08-11-2023 , the main output that i want is that whatever date i enter the function should get what day is on that date and should calculate and return me same day of next week with new date , suppose on 01-11-2023 Wednesday then function should return 08-11-2023 Wednesday.

I want some to help me with the calculations.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)